# SQL: SELECT where one of many columns contains 'x' and result is not "NULL"

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a piece of code that I realized is probably quite inefficient, though I'm not sure how to improve it.

Basically, I have a database table like this:

[Example DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXMD0.png)

Any or several of columns A-G might match my search query. If that is the case, I want to query `VALUE` from that row. I need `VALUE` not to equal `NULL` though, so if that's the case, it should keep looking. If my query were `abc`, I'd want to obtain `correct`.

Below is my current code, using a database named `db` with a table `table`.

```
cur=db.cursor()

data="123"
fields_to_check=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]

for field in fields_to_check:

    "SELECT Value FROM table WHERE {}='{}'".format(field,data)
    query=cur.fetchone()
    if query and query !="NULL":
        break

db.close()
```

I think that the fact that this performs 8 queries is likely very inefficient.

Comment: add `and VALUE IS NOT NULL` to the end of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur=db.cursor()

data="123"
fields_to_check=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
sub_query = ""

for field in fields_to_check:
    sub_query = sub_query + "or {}='{}' ".format(field,data)

if sub_query:
    query = "SELECT Value FROM table WHERE ("+ str(sub_query[2:]) +") and value IS NOT NULL;"

if query:
    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if rows:
      for row in rows:
        print(row)
```